# SSRS - Opening DataSet Property Windows Crashes Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reporting-services, visual-studio-2013, ssrs-2008

I have Web Application in MVC Framework having SSRS Reports inside..

I have designed couple of `.rdlc`  reports in my application.

Suddenly from yesterday, when i open `report Wizard` in New Report or open `Add new Dataset` in existing report, visual studio stops working.

but when i opened backup Project (backup taken before two days), it is working fine.. it allows adding new dataset or working correct report wizard in it..

so i think there is some setting that has been changed in my current project
(may be in `.csproj` file)

so what settings i need to change in my application...

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I have found something related to this error..

When i have added `ChilkatDotNet45.dll` in my Application and added code related it, after then i am getting this problem.. when i remove this dll file, all report stuffs working fine..

so i am close to this solution but dont know how to solve it...

what is the problem between **ChilkatDotNet45.dll** and **SSRS Reporting Service** ??? And how to solve it ???

Thanks....

Comment: I still got the same bug with Visual Studio 2015 Prof Update 3