# Visual Studio 2015 crashing after adding a report

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reporting-services, reporting

I already searched on Stackoverflow but I could only find this workaround. [Remove ChilkatDotNet45 DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29408764/ssrs-opening-dataset-property-windows-crashes-visual-studio-2013)

I have Visual Studio 2015 Professional Update 3. I am working with a web project and already have 3 reports that are working fine. The last time I changed the code was before the Windows Anniversary update. Maybe that's it. I don't know.

**Visual Studio crashes and restarts itself when I try to add a report with the report wizard.** But I am able to add a report without the wizard.

**Visual Studio crashes and restarts itself after I add a table to an empty report.**

I can still change my dataset and the "old" report that I created 2 months ago.

How can I fix my Visual Studio?

Comment: I am using SSRS; and the MSSQL Server is 2014.

Comment: Try repairing your Visual Studio installation; ensure you have the most up to date version of SQL Server Data Tools installed; reinstalling Visual Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. Try the following steps.

1. Create a new Project and add a Report using the Report Wizard. If this works then the problem is project related.
2. Add a report using the Report wizard in the Solution that is restarting, if you then receive an error stating something similar to : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient, Version=10.0.0. Redirect to the windows explorer C:\Windows\Assembly. Scroll down to "Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient" and make sure the version in question is installed .

If the version in this example 10.0.0. is not installed then you need to install the Correct Provider ADO.NET Version.

10.0.0 is Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 ADOMD.NET.

After installation , restart Visual Studio and create a report again using the Report Wizard. If this works , you should be able to open the Dataset

Let me know if this helped .